# Firefox v73.0b1 about:config stopped supporting filtering in address bar

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

Before version 73.0b1 it was possible to filter about:config by entering in address bar:

```
about:config?filter=browser
```

After latest update to 73.0b1 this does not work any more. No preferences shown at all. Manual filtering through search box on the page works as expected however.

Is this a bug or filtering from address bar will not be supported in the future?

OS: Windows 10x64

Comment: It's the result of the change from XUL to HTML. Could be just not implemented yet, could be an intentional choice. You're probably better off searching https://bugzilla.mozilla.org, or requesting the feature there if an issue does not already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this bugreport](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1501450) on Bugzilla, this feature was removed somewhere around october 2018 due to [security concerns](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1501450#c8):

> We explicitly decided to disallow deep linking into internal settings
>   to reduce attack surface, present and potential.
>
> To make a current example, "Open in New Tab" on an "about:config" link
>   on the web works after a reload, even though the first load is
>   disallowed. This probably wasn't foreseen originally, and we may have
>   similar cases in the future.
>
> Less steps for users isn't always better, see for example how the
>   security certificate override dialogs are explicitly designed to slow
>   down such operations. Deep linking into "about:config" to instruct
>   users, for example, to disable those security checks in less steps
>   could make it more attractive for attackers, and the link availability
>   may seem like an official endorsement of the use case.

Since the report is marked as `WONTFIX`, the feature most likely won't be reintroduced in the future.